# Powershell 非同期処理 RunspacePool

Tags: powershell, 非同期

下記のサイトを基に非同期処理を作成したいと思いました。

[RunspacePoolを使って、PowerShellを非同期実行](https://developers.gmo.jp/1964/)

非同期実行 PowerShellサンプルの行3,5,7を実行したいコマンドに変更しました。
◆実行したいコマンド:複数
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07"

エラーが発生せずに実行できていましたが、Powershellを再起動したら、エラーが発生するようになりました。

Powershellの関数や配列を調べましたが、解決までたどり着けずにいます。
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

**エラー内容**

```
AsyncPowershell : The term 'AsyncPowershell' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\xxxxx\Async\sample.ps1:11 char:8
+ $res = AsyncPowershell $PSCmds
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AsyncPowershell:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

#Powershellコマンドの並列実行オプションで解決しました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/using-psjobs?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: その状態で変更しない参照記事のままのスクリプトは動作しますか？ そして差し支えなければ変更して問題が発生した部分を掲載してください。公開できないようなら公開出来て問題が再現するものを見つけてそれに挿し替えて提示してみて下さい。そういった違いや原因を見つける作業記録の提示も助言や回答を得る助けになります。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。

その状態で変更しない参照記事のままのスクリプトは動作しますか？
⇒いえ、動作しませんでした。※記事の動画では動いているので、不思議に思っています。
　なお、Powershell ISEで下記をコメントアウトして実行するとPowershell ISEでは動作するようになりました。ただ、コメントアウトを外したり、付けたりしましたが、動作する時としない時があります。挙動が一定ではなく困惑しています。Power shell ISEで成功した状態のファイルでPowershell ISEで実行するとエラーになります。
　"New-Item -Path 'C:\Users\00.SizeUp\Async\Test.txt' -ItemType File"

Comment: 詳細についてはコメントで応答するのではなく質問記事自身を分かりやすいように編集して追記してください。あとこんな記事 [Running cmdlets in parallel using PowerShell jobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/using-psjobs?view=azurermps-6.13.0) でPowerShell自身に並列実行機能があったり、またAzureRMは(名前の違う)次の版数が出ていて終了に向かいつつあるようですが。

Comment: 記事の共有ありがとうございます。
いただいた内容で解決することができました。
AzureRMについては、環境上それしか利用できないためとなります。
今後いただいた指摘を基に質問したいと思います。

Comment: 解決した場合には、質問に直接追記してしまうのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してみてください。